# How to listen for event $emit in parent component without declaring on{eventName} in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm wondering if its possible to emit events from child component and listen in parent without using the convenient @event{eventMame} syntax. I'm using a plugin that introduces this problem.

I'm using the vuetable2 component and to attach actions to rows, I have to do something like the following:

```
{
  name: '__component:custom-actions',
  title: 'Actions',
  titleClass: 'text-center',
  dataClass: 'text-center'
}
```

I haven't been able / don't know how to attach an event listener using the @ to the custom-actions component.

I've tried the following in the created method:

```
created = () => {
  this.$on('eventName', this.methodName');
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

In the custom-actions component I'm doing:

```
this.$emit('eventName');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a fat arrow to define the created hook. `this` will point to the `window`, not Vue, and both `this.methodName` and `this.$on` will be undefined. Use

```
created(){
  this.$on('eventName', this.methodName');
}
```

or

```
created: function(){
  this.$on('eventName', this.methodName');
}
```

#### Post Comment Edit

You can use a bus to communicate through multiple layers of components. Outside of your components, declare a [bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

```
const bus = new Vue();
```

In your nested component

```
bus.$emit('eventName');
```

In your parent

```
created(){
  bus.$on('eventName', this.methodName');
}
```

Comment: I tried with fat arrow, and those 2 you mention. Nothing.

Comment: @AndresZapata is the child a direct child or a layer or more down?

Comment: I just checked and I think is not a direct child.

Comment: @AndresZapata In that case, you may want to use a bus. I'll edit.

Comment: @AndresZapata See if that edit doesn't work for you.